# how to clear the little red flag in the corner of the kendo grid cell

Tags: kendo-grid

I am allowing users to edit some cells of the grid.  For example, when they enter a date cell, a datepicker pops out and they select a date.  This action of changing the cell contents fires the grid's `save` event and it causes a little red flag to appear in the corner of the cell.

I've tried setting the dirty property to false:

```
   save: function (e) {
        // here, save the row to the database for "real-time" saves after every change
        // no need to hit a Save button
        // <snip>
        e.model.dirty = false;  // does not remove the red flag
    }
```

but that does not clear the red flag. What is the proper way to clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to it's name, the kendo grid's "save" event does not commit the modified data to the server.  It merely means that the data entered in the UI widget has been "saved" to the bound data.  It will still display the dirty flag because it is still volatile data which has not yet been committed to the server.

To actually commit the data you need to call the grid's [saveChanges method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-saveChanges). This method merely calls the grid's dataSource's [sync method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sync) which you could do alternatively.  Either way, once you do this and the post completes successfully, the red flags will disappear.

One last thing, if you set the grid's dataSource's [autoSync property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-autoSync) to true, the dataSource will perform a sync whenever any changes occur.  That is, each grid "save" event will actually mean that the data was committed to the server.

Comment: If I am going to be handling the updates myself, in the `save` event after every *cell* change, and therefore have no update method defined for the grid as a whole, can the `sync` method still be called? In this particular app, any row with at least one cell of data needs to be saved right away, without the user having to click a Save button.

Comment: Yes, you can call grid.saveChanges from within the grid's save event handler to immediately save the data and make the red flags go away.

Answer (score 2):

I used this command to clear the flags.

```
$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Telerik Support they recommend you do it using CSS.

```css
.k-grid .k-dirty {
  display: none;
}
```